# Search for an element in a LinkedList

Tags: c

I'm currently creating a linked list of strings that user enters. As of right now I have my linked list working (I just have to free the memory). However, I'm trying to detect for commas in the user input. If there is a comma make the linked list print out a new line, and just ignore the commas.

Any advice?

**For example:**

Enter a string:

hello,world,how,are,you

**The output is currently:**

hello,world,how,are,you

**The output should be:**

hello

world

how

are

you

Here's my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct Word
{
    char* data;
    struct Word* next;
};

struct Word* ptr = NULL;


void insert(char c)
{
    struct Word* temp = (struct Word*)malloc(sizeof(struct Word));

    temp->data = c;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (ptr) {
        struct Word* temp1 = ptr;

        while(temp1->next != NULL) {
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }

        temp1->next = temp;

    } else {
        ptr = temp;
    }

}

void print() {

    struct Word *temp;
    temp = ptr;

    while(temp != NULL) {

        printf("%c", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;

    }

    printf("\n");

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;

    printf("enter a string\n");
    while (((c=getchar())!=EOF) && c!='\n') {
        insert((char)c);
    }

    print(); /*print the list*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you using pointer-to-char to store a simple char! This answer is also plain wrong in that it doesn't instruct to do the correct thing: `char *data` should have been `char data`, now the code is full of undefined behaviours - you should compile with all warnings enabled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print every word in the new line you just have to modify your print statement to check for `,` character in the linked list.

```
void print() {

struct Word *temp;
temp = ptr;
char c;

while(temp != NULL) {

    if (temp->data == ',') {
        printf("\n");
        temp = temp->next;
    } else {
        printf("%c", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

}

   printf("\n");

}
```

This will check if there is a `,` in the linked list and print a `\n` to print newline character and move to the next node.

Also you should free your linked list after the program is complete to avoid memory leaks.

```
void freeData(struct Word* head)
{
   struct Word* tmp;

   while (head != NULL)
    {
       tmp = head;
       head = head->next;
       free(tmp);
    }

}
```

[Code link](http://ideone.com/J4dN6O)

Just try it out.

Comment: When you thought it wasn't that simple....uh thanks so much! When compiling it states a warning message: comparison between pointer and integer for the new if statement on temp->data == ','....any idea for a fix?

Comment: @Ayush wat, no!

Comment: @Karth to fix the error you must declare `data` as `char`, not `char*`. This is due to other things too, such that you don't need pointers to store a single char, and you don't alloc() memory for the pointer `char *data`.